# Automatic route calculation from A to B with JavaScript + Google Distance Matrix Service

Tags: javascript

My goal is to automate process of route calculation from A to B in Google Maps by using JavaScript + Google Distance Matrix Service. I would like to find route which is the fastest (based on current traffic). Script should calculate route by using current date and time.

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
function init() {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
  var origin = 'Great,Lake,8';
  var destination = 'Lake,Great,21';
  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [origin],
    destinations: [destination],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    drivingOptions: {
            departureTime: new Date(Date.now()),  // for the time N milliseconds from now.
        trafficModel: "best_guess"
        }
}, function(response, status) {
    if (status !== google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {

<!--     The same accessing of elements in object
     -->    
<!--   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += '1)' +  JSON.stringify(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text) + '<br>';
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += '2)' +  JSON.stringify(response.rows[0].elements[0]['distance']['text']) + '<br>';;
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += '3) RESPONSE: ' +  JSON.stringify(response) +'<br><br>'; -->

      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += 'RESULT: ' +  JSON.stringify(response);

alert(response.originAddresses[0] + ' ' + response.destinationAddresses[0] + ' ==> ' + response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text + ' ' + response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text);
    }
  });
}
</script>
<body onload="init()">
<div id="result">
</div>
</body>
```

Code works only if drivingOptions is removed. But I need this object - because I would like to calculate route based on traffic situation. I am executing script in https://jsfiddle.net/ - so I don't see any errors - except that when I removed drivingOptions object I saw that pop up with time and distance shown in pop up.

Comment: I don't see any question or description a problem to solve

Comment: @Arkej Code works only if drivingOptions is removed. But I need this object - because I would like to calculate route based on traffic situation.

Comment: Please update your question with that information, also with information about type of error that your `object` causes. It will make easier for other users to help you.

Comment: First problem solved - now script is working even with `drivingOptions` object. How I managed it? Just addeed `key` parameter to API. But now problem time which I see in Google Maps and in my script is different - it's less than on real map with real traffic conditions. I have tried `duration_in_traffic` field but no luck.

Comment: @MikhailR values will be different as they are different API's